# How to check if a query that return multiple rows contains a one of multiple values?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have user_role table were a user can be assigned multiple roles. I want a query which will checks if a particular user is assigned 'admin' or 'superadmin' role (checking for more roles may be required in the future). I tried to do it using PLSQL by selecting every role for a user and passing it to a variable, then checking if the any of those selected roles is either 'admin' or 'superadmin'. It became a bit complicated. How may I solve this issue?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SQL> with user_role (user_id, role) as
  2    (select 1, 'admin'      from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'superadmin' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'clerk'      from dual union all
  5     select 2, 'superadmin' from dual union all
  6     select 3, 'manager'    from dual
  7    )
  8  select user_id,
  9    max (case when role in ('admin', 'superadmin') then 'yes' else 'no' end ) is_admin
 10  from user_role
 11  group by user_id
 12  order by user_id;

   USER_ID IS_ADMIN
---------- ----------
         1 yes
         2 yes
         3 no

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a particular user, you can do:

```
select (case when exists (select 1
                          from user_role ur
                          where ur.role in ('admin', 'superadmin') and user_id = :user_id
                         )
             then 'yes' else 'no'
        end) as has_role
from dual
```